# mutual tls authentication between app service and function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

i want to establish one way tls authentication system between app service and function app.
Inside app service and function app i've uploaded private and public certificates from "certificate" blade.
now whenever i make request to function app api i get 403, which certificate (private/public) should i send in request header (X-ARR-ClientCert), should i do this step manually from code ? if yes then what's the purpose of uploading certificates from "certificate" blade and how to load them from nodejs? this is how i'm invoking function app api from app service:

```
 const response = await axios.get(
  "https://test-az-fn.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTrigger1"
);
```

i've enabled client certificate mode to "required" as shown below inside function app,
added "WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES" inside application settings of app service.
[image]